# How can I cancel a database query in ASP.NET when the user's browser disconnects?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asynchronous

My ASP.NET (3.5) app allows users to run some complex queries that can take up to 4 minutes to return results.

When I'm doing a long loops of code, I'll check `Response.IsClientConnected()` occasionally so I can end the page if the user closes their browser or hits the stop button.

But when querying SQL Server, my .NET code is blocked at the call to `GetDataReader()`.

Is there a straightforward way to do GetDataReader() asynchronously so I can wait around for it but still check, say, every 5-10 seconds to see if the user is still connected, and bail on the database query if they've left?

Or is there some other alternative I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the sqlcommand's BeginExecuteReader to get an asynch sqlreader
[example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a674khd%28VS.80%29.aspx)

not 100% sure if thats what you need?

[link showing cancel](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ADO/173_ADONet_20_Features_-_Asynchronous_SqlCommand_Execution.aspx)

Comment: I'm thinking this is, thanks! Will do some research later and make sure this fits the bill before I accept.

Comment: @richardtallent I have never used it but the additional link i added shows more examples and suggests using the cancel method on the command object

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating an object that has `Start()` and `Wait()` methods encapsulating your query.  Internally use a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) to wait on the query completing.  You'll use the `Set()` function when the query is complete, and the `WaitOne()` or `WaitOne(TimeSpan ts)` method to wait on it in your `Wait()` method.